# Single Database Call With Many Parameters vs Many Database Calls With Few Parameters

Tags: oracle, ado.net

I am writing a Content Management System which can store meta-data about different document-types. Each document-type has its own set of meta-data fields. For example a Letter has fields like "To", "From", "ToAddress", "FromAddress" etc whereas a MinutesOfMeeting has fields like "DateHeldOn", "TimeHeldOn", "AttendedBy" etc.

I am saving this information in database in two tables: General and Specific. General store information which is common to all types such as DocumentOwnerName, DocumentCreatedDate, DocumentSize etc. Specific table is not one table but a set of 35 different tables, one for each document-type.

I have a page which contains a grid in which I show list of document. One record corresponds to one document. Since the grid is made to show documents of all types therefore first row may show a letter, second a MinutesOfMeeting, third a Memo etc.

I have also made a search feature where user can set criteria on basis of which documents list is retrieved. To make it work, there are four search-related parameters for each of the field in each of the specific tables, and all of these parameters are passed to a central procedure. This procedure then filter out records on basis of criteria.

The problem is, dealing with 35 different document-types, each having like 10 fields, I end up with more than a thousand parameters for the procedure. This is a maintenance nightmare. I am looking for a solution.

One solution is to deal with each of the specific table individually, getting back Ids, then union them. This is fine, except that I have to make 36 different calls to the database, one each for a specific table plus one for the general table.

It all boils down to a simple architecture choice: Should I make a single database call passing many parameters or should I make many database calls passing few parameters.

Which approach is more preferable and why?

Edit: The web-server and database-server are on the same machine. Therefore, network speed shouldn't matter.

Comment: can u please shorten your question......

Comment: Or at least make it easier for people to understand what the core question is. :-)

Comment: Also note that as long as you're within the boundary of a single transaction, multiple queries (especially if via prepared statements or stored procedures) won't be significantly slower than a single mega-query.

Comment: @Abhinav etc: Shortened.

Comment: @Donal: Since its a data-retrieval procedure, not a data-modification procedure, therefore no transactions are involved.

Comment: Why does each field in each table need four different search parameters?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you probably don't want to have the web server and database on the same machine.  How much are you paying per CPU for Oracle, and can you afford to pay that much per CPU for your web server?

Comment: Transactions _are_ involved (assuming the whole database isn't configured to be readonly to everyone) because they're required as part of ensuring that the values read are consistent. To be fair, read transactions aren't nearly as expensive as write ones.

Answer (score 1):

When designing an API where I need a procedure to take a large number of related parameters, or even a variable list of parameters, I use record types, e.g.:

```
TYPE param_type IS RECORD (
   To
   From
   ToAddress
   FromAddress
   DateHeldOn
   TimeHeldOn
   AttendedBy
);

PROCEDURE do_search (in_params IN param_type);
```

The structure of the record is up to you, of course. If the procedure is coded to ignore the record elements that are NULL, then all the caller needs to do is set those elements that are required, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
   p param_type;
BEGIN
   p.DateHeldOn := DATE '2012-01-01';
   do_search(p);
END;
```

Comment: This approach is more maintainable despite the fact that I have to manage 35 different udts. The quantity of "substance" sent from front remains same, though more organized. I tried objects in oracle, making one for each table, but since we cannot have partial objects therefore readability is VERY decreased. Still, interesting approach, thanks.